# Swift: Back Button shows in Storyboard but not Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, button, storyboard

Back Button shows in StoryBoard but not Simulator.

I added a segue from `TableViewController` to `DetailViewController` to pass data. The Storyboard automatically shows a Back Button on `DetailViewController`, but when I run the Simulator, the button doesn't show up.

This is my Storyboard:

[image]

A closer look of  `TableViewController` and `DetailViewController`:
[image]

But in my Simulator the button doesn't show up:

[image]

The hierarchy of the whole project:

[image]

I want to know where to configure the back button(in my segue?), or instead deleting the button(not letting it show in the Storyboard) so I can create one myself.

The code of my segue in my `TableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailView", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch (segue.destination, sender) {
    case (let controller as DetailViewController, let indexPath as NSIndexPath):
        controller.receivedName = storeList[indexPath.row].name!
        controller.receivedDesc = storeList[indexPath.row].desc!
        controller.receivedRate = storeList[indexPath.row].rate
        controller.receivedUrl = storeList[indexPath.row].url!

    default:
        print("unknown segue")
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: use hierarchy debugger to check that there is no view appears on the top of the back button

Comment: Your table view controller is inside UINavigationController right?

Comment: Also may you check that there is no UIAppearance configured for the navigation bar and the navigation items appearance is not configured to use the same color as the navigation bar

Comment: Can you check your Storyboard segue kind? is it "show (Push)" or "show detail" or present modally? It should be Push if you want Back enabled.

Comment: @Anand Hi, it's Show(Push)

Comment: @plamkata__ Hi, it's `class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating`. Do you mean I should add a Navigation Controller between my `TableViewController` and `DetailViewController`?

Comment: @A.Munzer Hi, the hierarchy shows no view on top of the button (it doesn't even show there's a back button). I updated my question with a screenshot of the hierarchy.

Comment: @VanessaLeung - your table view controller must be embedded in UINavigationController. Would you show the whole storyboard or at leas where this table view controller is located?

Comment: Can you show the hole storyboard(including the tools in the right side)?
I suspect that the is no navigation controller .

Comment: @plamkata__ Hi I just updated my question with screenshots of the storyboard and hierarchy. I did link the `TableViewController` with a `NavigationController`

Comment: @ironRoei Hi I just updated my question with screenshots of the storyboard and hierarchy. There is no navigation controller between my TableViewController and DetailViewController.

Comment: @VanessaLeung i think the issue it with the embed navigation vc.
i dont think it is embed properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial view controller in the storyboard is actually the TabelViewController (you can see there is an arrow to it).

Thats' why when you start the scene and the TableViewController shows but it is not embedded in the navigation because the navigation controller has never been created.

Just change which is the initial view controller to be the navigation controller or any other before the navigation controller which holds the TableViewController.

You can just drag the arrow to change the initial controller in the storyboard

Comment: Oh yes, that's my problem! When I designed the TableViewController I set it as initial view so I could jump to it immediately on the simulator. But I forgot to change it back. Thank you sooo much!